# How can I click on "forgotten password" when I want to retrieve my password?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on forgotten password if my attempt to login failed but I can't figure out why it doesn't work:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
import time

#Login for each user
user = "user@gmail.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://fr.linkedin.com/")
login = driver.find_element(By.ID, "session_key")
mdp = driver.find_element(By.ID, "session_password")
login.send_keys(user)
mdp.send_keys("Pass123")
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element(By.ID,"id=sign-in-form__submit-btn")
button.click()
time.sleep(4)  
#If password is not good then we click on forgotten password
if(button.click() == True):
    pass
else:
    button_forgotpassword = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID,"sign-in-form__forgot-password"))
    time.sleep(10)
    button_forgotpassword.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Without knowing the web site you're logging into, how can we possibly guess what the problem is?

Comment: If the code is doing something you didn't expect, you have to **tell us** what the code did.  If you're getting an error message, you have to **show it** to us.  You can't just say "it doesn't work" and expect us to magically know what happened.

Comment: Yes, I understand thanks for your help.
The site is linkedin and the browser shuts down once the click on the submit button occured. I edited my code.

Comment: What I wanted to say on my original post is that , I want to click on forgotten password if the username or password is not good. If it is then it connects the user to linkedin.

Comment: nothings going to work after "driver.quit()" is called.  After clicking submit you have to test for an expected condition of some kind.  Test the DOM for whatever occurs when the user successfully logs in.  ex: use findElements with a proper webdriverwait and target the element that appears to access the user profile.  If the webelement array returned is empty, the login probably failed.  You could also test for a DOM element that only appears when the login failed.  (maybe a "login failed" message)  Branch accordingly.

Comment: When I run code the it raise error (in console/terminal) because it can't find `"id=sign-in-form__submit-btn"` and it finishs code and it closes browser. Did you run code in console/terminal/shell to see error messages?

Comment: first: you search `"id=sign-in-form__submit-btn"` but it is `"sign-in-form__submit-btn"` without `id=`. Second: this button doesn't have `id` but `data-id` and this is big difference. it may need to use `xpath` to find this element. Like `(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-id="sign-in-form__submit-btn"]')`

Comment: finally: I'm not sure but I think `click()` always returns `None` - so checking `== True` or `== False` is totally useless.

Comment: BTW: did you test behavior of this page in browser? When password is wrong then it load page `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit` - and maybe you should check `url`. But sometimes it may load page with `Captcha`.

Comment: Thanks pcalkins ans  furas , i am going to test this and i am going to check the url , if the url is the same , it will click on the link "forgotten password" if it is not it will move on . Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

First: you search `"id=sign-in-form__submit-btn"` but it is `"sign-in-form__submit-btn"` without `id=`.
Second: this button doesn't have `id` but `data-id` and this is big difference. It may need to use `xpath` to find this element.

```
find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-id="sign-in-form__submit-btn"]')
```

---

I'm not sure but I think `click()` always returns `None` - so checking `== True` or `== False` is useless. You have to check something different. You may check if it loaded different page - `driver.current_url`.

When password is wrong then it loads page `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit`.
But sometimes it may load page with `Captcha`.

---

Full code which I used for testing.

Because it always ask me for `Verification` so I couldn't test button for reseting password.

I also uses `input()` to pause code and it keep open browser and I can check HTML and CSS in `DevTools` in browser, or I can pass Verification.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
import time

#Login for each user
user = "user@gmail.com"
password = "Pass123"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://fr.linkedin.com/")

time.sleep(3)

login = driver.find_element(By.ID, "session_key")
mdp   = driver.find_element(By.ID, "session_password")
login.send_keys(user)
mdp.send_keys(password)

#button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id=sign-in-form__submit-btn")
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-id="sign-in-form__submit-btn"]')
button.click()

time.sleep(4)  

#print('url:', driver.current_url, driver.current_url == 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit')

if driver.current_url == 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit':
    try:
        button_forgotpassword = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID, "sign-in-form__forgot-password"))
        button_forgotpassword.click()
        # TODO run other code
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception:', ex)
elif driver.current_url.startswith('https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/challenge/'):
    print("It asks for Verification.")
    input("\n*** Press ENTER when you finish verification ***\n")    
    # TODO run other code
else:
    print("Maybe you logged in.")
    
# keep browser open so I can test HTML and CSS    
input("\n*** Press ENTER to exit ***\n")    
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the code didn't work:

```
button = driver.find_element(By.ID,"id=sign-in-form__submit-btn")
```

In the previous code firstly, you forgot to remove the "id="
secondly, for some reason, the ID and the Class name of that button are not working But I used an extension called "Selectors Hub" and I copied the Xpath from them and it works..
Try that...
Here are some references:
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/selectorshub/ndgimibanhlabgdgjcpbbndiehljcpfh

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/#no-such-element-exception

Here is the full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
import time

#Login for each user
user = "user@gmail.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://fr.linkedin.com/")
login = driver.find_element(By.ID, "session_key")
mdp = driver.find_element(By.ID, "session_password")
login.send_keys(user)
mdp.send_keys("Pass123")
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"""//button[@type='submit']""")
button.click()
time.sleep(4)  
#If the password is not good then we click on forgotten password
if(button.click() == True):
    pass
else:
    button_forgotpassword = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID,"sign-in-form__forgot-password"))
    time.sleep(10)
    button_forgotpassword.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.quit()
```

for security reasons, It didn't work with me after I got redirected to the "forgotten password" URL.